What is the "Hard Drive & Wing Man" title card in Community a reference to?
In the Community episode "Lawnmower Maintenance and Postnatal Care" (S06E02), Jeff and Elroy successfully extract Dean Pelton from his VR headset after he's been immersed in the virtual world for four hours.
As they discuss the Dean's recovery, Elroy assures Jeff that "he'll be back to his old self in an hour." Jeff quips, "Great, do you have a way to fix that?" They share a laugh, and then the screen freezes, and a title card appears, displaying "Hard Drive & Wing Man."

Given Community's penchant for movie and TV show references, I suspect this might be a nod to a TV show. Does anyone know which show (if any) is being referenced here? If it's not a direct TV show reference, what exactly is the joke alluding to?

It's a reference to 80s style title cards; https://i.pinimg.com/564x/b3/b7/a7/b3b7a7c5d078e0d29503a1c023512cb2.jpg

I gather from googling around that this is an in-joke on Dan Harmon's extensive podcast series. Winger is the Winger Man and there was a gigantic hard drive on set or something.

Isn't Elroy a handy man, and usually involved with fixing hardware, and "Hard Drive" a suitable '80s hero name? The joke seems like a more interesting (and meta, like everything Harmon) alternative to a rimshot, somewhat "ironizing" an otherwise typical/obvious joke.
